# How to incorporate bugfixes

Tags: git, version-control, repository

I have the following situation, where I am unsure what the best workflow is. I need definitely some advice:

**We have a:**
 - a repository `origRepo` (branches: `master`) and a
 - a fork `fork` (branches: `master`, remote branch `origRepo/master`)

**We can assume that the `master` branche is always updated, in the repo `fork` by**

```
git fetch origRepo/master
git checkout master
git merge origRepo/master
```

Some user worked on the `fork` repo and made some branch `test`.
What workflow should the user in the following scenarios apply:

**Scenario 1:**
He is working and just notices a bug in file **A** which should immediately be updated in `master`.

1. Should he commit the bug fix of file **A** in a separate commit
   "BUGFIX" in branch `test`? How to proceed?? Merge `test` with `master` does not work as  there is still unfinished work.
2. Should he `pull master` ? to get the recent version of master, then
   checkout a branch `bugfix` from `master`, commit the fixed file
   **A** there, and then merge `bugfix` with both `master` and `test` to get the changes in both branches.

I have problems understanding how he gets the modified file **A** in branch `test` into the `bugfix` branch to be able to commit. I mean, editing file **A** again in branch `bugfix` is redundant.

**Scenario 2:**
He had committed several times and his work directory is now really convoluted with unfinished work and his working directory is clean (`git status`). He realizes now that he has several updated files which should be updated in `master` branch as well, how does he do this?

**The last problem I have is:**
How should the `test` branch if it is ready to merge, be merged into `master` if one wants only to merge selective files. Can we do this with:

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff --no-commit test
git add -i  # to interactively stage and unstage files which should not be merged into master again, because the might have been changed only for testing purposes.
git commit -m "merging test"
```

I appreciate really any comment about some hints about these scenarios. I am pretty much lost about what to do properly in this moments? CherryPicking? Merging?
I mostly do not want to `rebase` as I dont like this tool so much, I rather want a `merge`, which is more visual for me.